# Loading a saved dictionary (containing objects as values) from a file using pickle

Tags: python, load, pickle

I am currently trying to learn Python and having learned the basics I decided to try to make an address book program. I am having trouble loading the contacts after they have been saved though. Here's what I have so far,

```
import pickle

contacts = {}

class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, address):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.address = address

Name = input('Contacts Name - ')
Phone = input('Phone Number - ')
Address = input('Address - ')

contacts[Name] = Contact(Name, Phone, Address)

with open('SaveFile', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(contacts, f)
```

this all seems to work fine and the contacts dictionary is saved but when I try to load the contacts back after I have cleared the dictionary it does not work for some reason,

```
def load():
    with open('SaveFile', 'rb') as f:
        contacts = pickle.load(f)
```

I don't get an error message but the dictionary stays empty.
Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could it be a missing "return contacts" in your load() function?

Answer (score 1):

Variables have scope. The `contacts` variable you assigned to within the `load` function has no relationship to the `contacts` you defined as a global variable. The simplest solution would be to make your function `return` the newly loaded contacts, letting you replace the existing dictionary:

```
def load_contacts():
    with open('SaveFile', 'rb') as f:
        new_contacts = pickle.load(f)

    return new_contacts

...

contacts = load_contacts()
```

If you do want to directly access the global `contacts` variable from within the `load` function, you can use the `global` keyword to tell Python that you're referring to `contacts` from the global scope:

```
def load():
    global contacts

    with open('SaveFile', 'rb') as f:
        contacts = pickle.load(f)
```

You could also avoid assigning to your global `contacts` and instead modify it:

```
def load():
    contacts.clear()

    with open('SaveFile', 'rb') as f:
        new_contacts = pickle.load(f)

    contacts.update(new_contacts)
```

The difference in the last example is that you're directly working with the *object* referred to by `contacts`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
pickle.load(open("SaveFile", 'rb'))
```

Comment: Actually, the "right" (in quotes) way to open a file is using the WITH statement. it's more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the info, wasn't aware of that.